# Does $(x_1v = x_2v) \implies (x_1 = x_2)$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ are any scalars and $v \in V$ is any vector in a vector space $V$, is it true that

$$
(x_1v = x_2v) \implies (x_1 = x_2)
$$

---

I guess this would be termed a cancellation law, but I swear I could not find this result in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right". I need this result (if it's true) to justify some other thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**V** can be a zero vector. So its true only when you say that V is not zero vector.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this would be termed a cancellation law, but I swear I could not find this result in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right".

It is not in LADR, but the result follows from the problem $2$, EXERCISES $1$.B in LADR:

> Suppose $a\in\Bbb F$, $v\in V$, and $av=0$. Prove that $a=0$ or $v=0$.

Therefore, $x_1v=x_2v\implies(x_1-x_2)v=0\implies x_1=x_2  \ \ \text{or} \  \ v=0$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for showing the result.